# Inverted Axis Panning Direction with 2 Range Axes in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a chart with 2 range axes. I have the datasets mapped properly to the two axes, but when I pan the chart, they move in opposite directions (one goes up, one goes down)? Is there a way to invert the pan direction while maintain the order of the axis labels? I want negative values on top of both axes, and positive on the bottom; I just need the movements synced.

It's not obvious to me if the pan direction is setable in any way (although I could see this being desirable).

I [asked this](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116619) on the official JFreechart Forum, but haven't had any luck with replies yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From examining the source code, it appears that direction is tied directly to inverted labels.   I just had to extend my inherited plot and overload 1 function:

public void panRangeAxes(double percent, PlotRenderingInfo info,
            Point2D source)

to control this.